# MySQL Workbench folder does not exist after improper shut down

Tags: mysql, installation, workbench

This morning I installed MySQL sever (ver. 5.6). I used MySQL Workbench to create schema, users and tables I needed for my development.

After several hours of work I just closed my laptop without closing applications.

When I came home, I realized that laptop in meantime fully shut down (probably ran out of battery).

I tried to run MySQL Workbench application and got error
 **Workbench Restore: c:/user/.../AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench folder does not exist.** I checked hard drive and this folder does exist.

Now, everything is gone, my schemas, tables, users and I can't start Sql server no more.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks